# How do I compile and run a Matlab script in Sublime Text 3 using mcc?

Tags: matlab, unix, sublimetext3, mcc

I set up mcc and made a new Build System trying to get the same experience as the Command Window in Matlab.

Building an .sh file and running it with:

```
"shell_cmd": "mcc -m '$file'"
```

takes a long time and does not work properly. Surely, there must be a simpler way. How do I get the output of Matlabs Command Window in Sublime as if would run the script in Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly create a build system for matlab and edit the build file as:

```
{
    // Change path to matlab.exe per local settings
    "cmd": ["C:/Program Files/MatLab/R2016b/bin/matlab.exe", 
            "-r", "\"run('$file')\""],
    "selector": "source.matlab",
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}"
}
```

Google and you will find more detailed instructions.